# Why I cannot convert unique_ptr to a raw pointer in assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

When writing a simple binary search tree insertion, I encountered a compilation error in g++ 4.7

```
error: cannot convert ‘node_ptr {aka std::unique_ptr<node>}’ to ‘node*’ in assignment
```

for the line `node* n = root.get()` in `bst_insert` function. I don't understand why?

```
struct node;

typedef std::unique_ptr<node> node_ptr;

struct node {
        node(int k) : key(k) {};
        int key;
        node_ptr left = nullptr;
        node_ptr right = nullptr;
};

void bst_insert(node_ptr& root, node_ptr z) {
    node* p = nullptr;
    node* n = root.get();
    while (n != nullptr) {
        p = n;
        n = z->key < n->key ? n->left : n->right;
    }
    if (p == nullptr)
        root = std::move(z);
    else if (z->key < p->key)
        p->left = std::move(z);
    else p->right = std::move(z);
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to save before trying to compile? Or compile a different copy of the file than the one you're editing? On several occasions I've seen that as the explanation for mystifying errors.

Comment: g++-4.7 gives the line of the error, and that's not the line you are claiming it is.

Answer (score 5):

```
n = z->key < n->key ? n->left : n->right;
```

This line. `n->left` and `n->right` are `std::unique_ptr`s and you are trying to assign unique ptr to raw pointer. Change that line to:

```
n = z->key < n->key ? n->left.get() : n->right.get();
```